# Safari Browser - WebSocket connection failed while sending 10KB binary data

Tags: websocket, safari

I'm creating a WebSocket connection to my server from the safari browser via console tab like below.

```
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:1200/WS_TEST?client=123&session=1234'); 
    socket.onopen = function (event) { 
        console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', event); 
    };
    
    socket.onmessage = function (event) { 
        console.log('Received buffer', event.data); 
    };
```

On Server:
For sending string

```
Socket.sendString("Hi");
```

For sending binary image data

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(File_path + "image.png");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[11000];
    int bytesRead;
    
    while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytesRead];
     System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, byteArray, 0, bytesRead);
     Socket.sendBytes(byteArray, false);
    }
```

Once the connection established, The server sends multiple data which includes text and binary data.

When the server sends binary data more than 10KB after sending text data in the same socket, the WebSocket connection is getting failed.

EX:
WebSocket Connection established
Data (Text): "Hi"
Data (Binary): just binary frame of size 11KB
WebSocket connection terminated due to a protocol error.

When the server send the binary data alone, the connection is not affected even the size is more than 100KBs
EX:
WebSocket Connection established
Data (Text): "Hi"
Data (Binary): just binary frame of size 100KB
WebSocket connection is live.

[Note: Issue only occurs in recent safari browser]

I tried to send Both text and binary data via the WebSocket connection in safari browser. But it failed with the error message as protocol error. I can only send a binary data below 10KB along with text data in the WebSocket connection. If I need to send a binary data more than 10KB, I should not send text data in the same connection.